# Selecionar option de um select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<select id="faturamento-mes-referencia">
    <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
    <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
    <option value="3">Março</option>
    <option value="4">Abril</option>
    <option value="5">Maio</option>
    <option value="6">Junho</option>
    <option value="7">Julho</option>
    <option value="8">Agosto</option>
    <option value="9">Setembro</option>
    <option value="10">Outubro</option>
    <option value="11">Novembro</option>
    <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
</select>
```

E javascript:

```
var mes = 8;
document.getElementById('faturamento-mes-referencia');
```

Eu gostaria de selecionar o `option` que tem `value="8"` baseando se na minha variável que é dinâmica e no caso apareceria Agosto, no projeto uso jquery caso facilite.

Tirando dúvidas gostaria do resultado assim:

```html
<select id="faturamento-mes-referencia">
    <option value="1">Janeiro</option>
    <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>
    <option value="3">Março</option>
    <option value="4">Abril</option>
    <option value="5">Maio</option>
    <option value="6">Junho</option>
    <option value="7">Julho</option>
    <option value="8" selected>Agosto</option>
    <option value="9">Setembro</option>
    <option value="10">Outubro</option>
    <option value="11">Novembro</option>
    <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Isso [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/kvvtrbr9/) já não resolveria seu problema?

Comment: Acho que a resposta do @Marconi é o que tu precisa então!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pelo que entendi o seu problema é mais simples do que parece. Entendi que você quer selecionar um *`option`* pelo valor.

Seu faltou você atribuir a variável mês no *`value`*.

***Veja funcionando:***

```js
var mes = 8;
document.getElementById('faturamento-mes-referencia').value = mes;
```

```html
<select id="faturamento-mes-referencia">
    <option value="1">Janeiro</option>                           
    <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>                           
    <option value="3">Março</option>                           
    <option value="4">Abril</option>                           
    <option value="5">Maio</option>                           
    <option value="6">Junho</option>                           
    <option value="7">Julho</option>                           
    <option value="8">Agosto</option>                           
    <option value="9">Setembro</option>                           
    <option value="10">Outubro</option>                           
    <option value="11">Novembro</option>                           
    <option value="12">Dezembro</option>                           
</select>
```

Comment: Eu leio e releio e não consigo achar que é isso que ele está pedindo, mas talvez seja D:

Comment: Cheguei essa conclusão, acho que ele só quer selecionar um option no select, rs! :)

Comment: Poxa eu escrevi um código tão bonito (fiquei bem feliz com o resultado até haha) para fazer tanto mais haha mas acho que tu tens razão e quando ele se manifestar eu apago minha resposta daí

Comment: Thiago nem vale a pena você apagar sua resposta, tá legal cara! Deixa lá ou edita!

Comment: É isso mesmo Marconi

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno bom que pude ajudar.

Comment: @Marconi seguindo tua sugestão editei o POST de forma a salvar o texto da OPTION numa variável e mudar o value do SELECT, mas ficou um exagero de código haha

Answer (score 3):

**GETELEMENTSBYTAGNAME INSIDE ANOTHER ELEMENT**

Em javascript puro é necessário selecionar somente os `<option>` dentro do `<select>` com o ID definido e encontrar seu valor, caso não haja retorna NULL:

```js
function selecionarTexto(elementId, cod) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var opt = elt.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++) {
      if(opt[i].value == cod) {
        alert(opt[i].text);
        elt.value = cod;
      }
    }
  return null;
}

// Se quiser utilizar jQuery fica assim:  
function testeComJquery(val) {
  alert($("#faturamento-mes-referencia option[value="+val+"]").text());
  return $("#faturamento-mes-referencia").val(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectErrado">
  <option value="1">Erro</option>                           
  <option value="2">Erro</option>                         
  <option value="4">Erro</option>                        
  <option value="5">Erro</option>   
</select>

<select id="faturamento-mes-referencia">
  <option value="1">Janeiro</option>                           
  <option value="2">Fevereiro</option>                         
  <option value="4">Abril</option>                        
  <option value="6">Junho</option>                           
  <option value="7">Julho</option>                           
  <option value="8">Agosto</option>                           
  <option value="9">Setembro</option>                           
  <option value="10">Outubro</option>                           
  <option value="11">Novembro</option>                           
  <option value="12">Dezembro</option>                           
</select>

<p><button onclick="selecionarTexto('faturamento-mes-referencia', 4)">TESTE</button> - Vai selecionar sempre Abril</p>

<p><button onclick="testeComJquery(7)">TESTE JQUERY</button> - Vai selecionar sempre Julho</p>
```

Comment: Eu gostaria de selecionar um `option` a partir de uma variável com o mesmo valor do `value`, tem como?

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno desculpa a má compreensão, o código agora busca sempre o index do elemento 4

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar a descrição do select selecionado:

```
$("#faturamento-mes-referencia option:selected").text();
```

Para pegar o value do select selecionado:

```
$("#faturamento-mes-referencia").val();
```

Para selecionar um select da sua option através do value do select:

```
$("#faturamento-mes-referencia").val(8); //(Agosto)
```

Para selecionar um select da sua option através da descrição do select:

```
var text1 = 'Agosto';
$("#faturamento-mes-referencia option").filter(function() {
    return this.text == text1; 
}).attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: Mas eu quero selecionar um option que no exemplo tem o `value=8` como faço?

Comment: Editei o post...

Comment: @ThalesChemenian nenhum das tuas opções funciona.

Answer (score -3):

O **Value** não deu certo no meu código e continuei até que deu certo assim:

```
document.getElementById('faturamento-mes-referencia').options.selectedIndex = mes;
```

Descobri o motivo que o meu select tinha dois valores

```
<option value="1, Volvo-Carlos">Volvo-Carlos</option>
```